# How to replicate a typing effect using jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to have the exact typing effect used on this page? https://www.braintreepayments.com/

```
<span class="writer" data-writer-command="['PayPal?', 'Apple Pay?', 'Venmo?', 'Bitcoin?']">Ve</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JSFiddle with the extracted library from the website : http://jsfiddle.net/8g6dsp0p/1/

You can initialize the script with this following code :

```
<span class="writer" data-writer-command="['PayPal?', 'Apple Pay?', 'Venmo?', 'Bitcoin?']"></span>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   new Writer
});
</script>
```

Comment: really thank you! How to avoid the lost paragraph when text in array is changed? http://jsfiddle.net/8g6dsp0p/2/

Comment: You can simply add a new CSS rule to the span `.writer { display: inline-block; }` [http://jsfiddle.net/8g6dsp0p/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/8g6dsp0p/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var word = "Venmo";
var cur = 1;
var intrvl = setInterval(function () {
   $('.writer').html(word.slice(0,cur));
   if(cur >= word.length) {
clearInterval(intrvl);
  }
  else{
   cur++;
  }
}, 500);
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/danegoqatu/1/)

The above jsBin has the code you require. it is not neatly formatted but code is correct.
Again to reproduce the code

```
<span clas="writer"></span>


    var words = ["Venmo", "alright", "done", "ok"];
var curWord = 0;



function writeWord(word, deleteWord) {
  var cur;
  if(deleteWord){    
    cur = deleteWord.length;
    var delIntrvl = setInterval(function () {

     if(!cur) {
      clearInterval(delIntrvl);
       if(curWord < (words.length - 1)) {
         writeWord(words[++curWord],"");  
       } 
       else {//if you dont need continous looping remove this else statement
         curWord = 0;
         writeWord(words[curWord],"");  
       }      
    }
    else{
      var reqWrd = deleteWord.slice(0,cur);
      console.log(reqWrd);
     $('.writer').html(reqWrd);
     cur--;
    }
    }, 200);
  }
  else {
    cur=1;
    var intrvl = setInterval(function () { 

     if(cur >= word.length) {
      clearInterval(intrvl);       
       writeWord("",word);
    }
    else{
      var reqWrd = word.slice(0,cur);
      console.log(reqWrd);
     $('.writer').html(reqWrd);
     cur++;
    }
    }, 200);


     }


        }

        writeWord(words[curWord], "");
```

Updating the code and also providing jsBin for continous looping
[ContinousLoopJsBin](http://jsbin.com/danegoqatu/1/)

Comment: Thank you but how about more than 1 different words?

Comment: In the example there is a "backspace" effect when changing the words

Comment: This is great! Any way to restart the loop of words when finished? because now it stops on the "o" of the deleted "ok"

Comment: i have edited the code and also added another jsbin. kindly upvote or accept it if you liked it!